# Slider/Trackbar alternative

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, custom-controls, trackbar

Anyone know of a custom control that looks like this [Volume control http://img806.imageshack.us/img806/9366/volumecontrol.png](http://img806.imageshack.us/img806/9366/volumecontrol.png) and works similarly to slider or trackbar?

I tried googling but all I found was [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c12101), w/c is similar to the built-in trackbar control in VS2008.

I don't use WPF; just C# 2.0.

Comment: Is it an option to make one youself. It can't be too hard. Just create an user control with a custom paint event and some mouse move statements.

Comment: well, the primary reason is that the users are already used to this control. this is implemented in c++, and we're porting this to c# and would need to keep the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to modify the code of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/ColorSlider.aspx) control to do what you want.

Comment: I ended up rolling my own and this helped me. Thanks, Kernow!

Comment: Here's another one I found just recently http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57127/MediaSlider-An-Alternative-to-the-Trackbar-Control